# How can we convert Loadrunner scripts into JMeter scripts

Tags: jmeter

Can some one please guide me "How to convert Loadrunner Scripts into JMeter scripts"?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I have no idea how to do that so trying to find options  and is it really possible and feasible to do as I never done earlier -Raj

Comment: Why not the other way? The latest versions of the LoadRunner controller can run Jmeter virtual users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool was released lately.

If you upload a ZIP of your LoadRunner script, it will convert it to JMeter or Selenium.
It might not be 100%, but it will tell you what it couldn't convert and save you a lot of troubles.

[shiftleft.blazemeter.com](https://shiftleft.blazemeter.com)
[image]

Comment: All though I am able to convert with the solution provided by Dmitri , I will try also this and let you know the result Rafael! And Thanks Rafael!-Raj

Comment: exist any way to convert it from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Record them (will work only for HTTP protocol and derivatives, i.e. Web Services).

1. **JMeter Configuration**. The fastest and the easiest way of setting up JMeter for recording is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) Feature.

   - Select `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` from JMeter's main menu
   - Expand `WorkBench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start" button

     [image: JMeter Template Recording]
2. **LoadRunner Configuration**

   - In VuGen press `F4` (having your script opened) to get into "RunTime Settings" dialog or use `Replay -> Runtime Settings` from the main menu
   - Click `Proxy -> Use custom proxy -> Use proxy server` and enter `localhost` as proxy and `8888` as a port (given you run JMeter on the same machine)

     [image: LoadRunner Proxy Configuration for JMeter recording]
3. Run your script with 1 VU and 1 Iteration. JMeter will capture the requests and convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! I will let you know the results

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! It worked!